# Symfony form type extension for custom types

Tags: symfony, inheritance, symfony-forms, symfony6

## STARTING SITUATION

I'm trying to create, with Symfony 6, a FormTypeExtension to extend my custom types.

Class hierarchy is the following:

```
AbstractType    <-- indeed this class is abstract
 +--MyBaseType
 |   +--MySubType1
 |   +--MySubType2
 +--MyOtherType
```

My FormTypeExtension:

```
class TranslatableTypeExtension extends AbstractTypeExtension
{
    /**
     * Should apply to MyBaseType plus MySubType1 and
     * MySubType2 by inheritance
     */
    public static function getExtendedTypes(): iterable
    {
        return [
            MyBaseType::class,
        ];
    }

    /**
     * Special option for these custom form types
     */
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver): void
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'translate_only' => false,
        ]);

        $resolver->setDefined(['translate_only']);
    }
}
```

My custom type classes:

```
class MyBaseType extends AbstractType
{
}

class MySubType1 extends MyBaseType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options): void
    {
        $builder
            ->add('blahblahblah', TextType::class, [
                'label' => 'blahblahblah',
        ])
        (etc.)
        ;
    }
}

(same for MySubType2)
```

In my controller:

```
class MySub1Controller extends AbstractController
{
    #[Route('/MySub1/{id}/translate', name: 'app_mysub1_translate')]
    public function translateMuSub1(MySub1Repository $mySub1Repository, EntityManagerInterface $entityManager, Request $request, int $id): Response
    {
        $mySub1 = $mySub1Repository->find($id);

        $form = $this->createForm(MySubType1Type::class, $mySub1, [
            'translate_only' => true,
        ]);
        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
            $mySub1 = $form->getData();
            $entityManager->persist($mySub1);
            $entityManager->flush();

            return $this->redirectToRoute('app_mysub1', ['id' => $id]);
        }

        return $this->renderForm('public/form/mysub1.html.twig', [
            'form' => $form,
        ]);
    }
}
```

This results is:

```
An error has occurred resolving the options of the form "App\Form\Type\MySub1Type": The option "translate_only" does not exist. Defined options are: (...)
```

## CONCLUSION

This error message means that the FormTypeExtension does not apply to MySubType1: the option translate_only is not reckognized as allowed.

## QUESTIONS

I see in the [Symfony Form Type Extension doc](https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/create_form_type_extension.html) that Form Extensions can be used for the classic [Form Types](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types.html) inheriting FormType. But I see nowhere written that we cannot use it the same way for customer types inheriting AbstractType.

1. Is it possible or not?
2. If possible, what am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance for your help, buddies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FormType inheritance is built on method getParent(). Probably, you should not extend `MyBaseType` but return it in `getParent()`

> getParent()
> When returning a (fully-qualified) class name here, Symfony will call each method of that type (i.e. buildForm(), buildView(), etc.)
> and **all its type extensions**, before calling the corresponding method
> of your custom type.

https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/create_custom_field_type.html#creating-form-types-created-from-scratch

```php
class MyBaseType extends AbstractType
{
}

class MySubType1 extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options): void
    {
        $builder
            ->add('blahblahblah', TextType::class, [
                'label' => 'blahblahblah',
        ])
        (etc.)
        ;
    }

    public function getParent()
    {
        return MyBaseType::class;
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, tell me if I'm wrong: 1) This solution works well for the matter of adding the `translate_only` option into the sub types having their `getParent()`pointing to `MyBaseType::class`, but 2) in the `TranslatableTypeExtension->buildForm()`, browsing the form fields with `$builder->all()` will only see fields added in the `MyBaseType->buildForm()`, and not those added in the `MySubType1->buildForm()`? --> This I'm trying to do, in order for the FormTypeExtension to adapt every child type in a generic manner. Maybe I should add it to the initial post.

Comment: Yes, you're right, the order of building is as follows: (1) `MyBaseType::buildForm()` -> (2) `TranslatableTypeExtension::buildForm()` - (3) `MySubType1::buildForm()`
You could access all form fields in TranslatableTypeExtension::finishView() or use form events

Comment: After having spent a lot of time to make it work as I wanted, I must admit that your answer was the best I could hope. It made me reconsider the way I was trying to do things. As I found in the `getParent()` doc you're pointing at, "If your custom type is based on another type (...) **Do not use PHP inheritance for this.**"

I finally opted for the FormTypeExtension to 1) add my `translate_only` option and also 2) dynamically add an event subscriber to browse the form fields after resolution of all the sub forms (POST_SET_DATA in order to let CollectionTypes build properly in PRE_SET_DATA).